# How to get member names on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord

I want to get the member names from a connected discord server, but the code I have right now just prints out `{"Security"}`:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

def get_member_names():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            yield member.name

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  people = set(get_member_names())
  print(people)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  print(message.content[0] == '>')


client.run(os.environ["BOT_PASSWORD"])
```

Answer (score 0):

use `guild.fetch_members(limit=None)` instead of `guild.members`.

See [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_members#discord.Guild.fetch_members)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the members property but if I recall correctly Discord removed this from their API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for doing this is through `client.get_all_members()`, which is an equivalent of the code you currently have, so I don't think this is an issue with your code. Your problem may be in what members your bot can actually *see*. If `{"Security"}` is all you're seeing, perhaps your bot can only see a member named Security. Make sure your bot has the proper permissions to view a channel that has members in it. Seeing members is reliant on the View Channel permission (For example, if someone doesn't have permission to view a channel, they won't appear in the member list, this works both ways)